# object.save() not a function error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I believe the issue revolves around the use of .save() and could possibly be associated with the object not having a .save() method.

/ This is the debugger output (thought I might as well clarify) /

```
Debugger listening on port 15454
Server started
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: examBoard.save is not a function
    at /home/ubuntu/workspace/tests/seeds.js:168:23
    at Immediate.Model.$wrapCallback (/home/ubuntu/workspace/tests/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3336:16)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (/home/ubuntu/workspace/tests/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mquery/lib/utils.js:137:16)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)


Process exited with code: 1
```

Just to help anyone find the actual issue, I have used `examBoad.save();` twice (once after the creation of all the examBoards and once close to the end of the program) and `question.save();` once, I believe the problem to be with `examBoard.save();`

```js
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var examBoard = require("./models/examBoard");
var question = require("./models/question");
var user = require("./models/user");

function seedDB() {
  examBoard.remove({}, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Could not remove examBoard data" + err);
    } else {
      examBoard.insertMany({
        name: "AQA",
        modules: [{
          name: "a",
          topics: [{
            name: "a1",
          }, {
            name: "a2",
          }, {
            name: "a3",
          }]
        }, {
          name: "b",
          topics: [{
            name: "b1",
          }, {
            name: "b2",
          }, {
            name: "b3",
          }]
        }, {
          name: "c",
          topics: [{
            name: "c1",
          }, {
            name: "c2",
          }, {
            name: "c3",
          }]
        }]
      }, {
        name: "OCR",
        modules: [{
          name: "a",
          topics: [{
            name: "a1",
          }, {
            name: "a2",
          }, {
            name: "a3",
          }]
        }, {
          name: "b",
          topics: [{
            name: "b1",
          }, {
            name: "b2",
          }, {
            name: "b3",
          }]
        }, {
          name: "c",
          topics: [{
            name: "c1",
          }, {
            name: "c2",
          }, {
            name: "c3",
          }]
        }]
      }, {
        name: "EXL",
        modules: [{
          name: "a",
          topics: [{
            name: "a1",
          }, {
            name: "a2",
          }, {
            name: "a3",
          }]
        }, {
          name: "b",
          topics: [{
            name: "b1",
          }, {
            name: "b2",
          }, {
            name: "b3",
          }]
        }, {
          name: "c",
          topics: [{
            name: "c1",
          }, {
            name: "c2",
          }, {
            name: "c3",
          }]
        }]
      });

      examBoard.save();

      question.insertMany({
        content: "<p>This is a question</p><br><img src='https://hd.unsplash.com/photo-1469537053566-3081fd1e0de2'><br><p>This is a bit after the image</p>",
        mark: 6,
        methods: [
          [{
            mark: 1,
            content: "1a"
          }, {
            mark: 2,
            content: "1b"
          }, {
            mark: 3,
            content: "1c"
          }],
          [{
            mark: 1,
            content: "2a"
          }, {
            mark: 2,
            content: "2b"
          }, {
            mark: 3,
            content: "2c"
          }],
          [{
            mark: 1,
            content: "3a"
          }, {
            mark: 2,
            content: "3b"
          }, {
            mark: 3,
            content: "3c"
          }]
        ]
      }, {
        content: "<p>This is a question</p><br><img src='https://hd.unsplash.com/photo-1465311440653-ba9b1d9b0f5b'><br><p>This is a bit after the image</p>",
        mark: 9,
        methods: [
          [{
            mark: 2,
            content: "1a"
          }, {
            mark: 3,
            content: "1b"
          }, {
            mark: 4,
            content: "1c"
          }],
          [{
            mark: 2,
            content: "2a"
          }, {
            mark: 3,
            content: "2b"
          }, {
            mark: 4,
            content: "2c"
          }],
          [{
            mark: 2,
            content: "3a"
          }, {
            mark: 3,
            content: "3b"
          }, {
            mark: 4,
            content: "3c"
          }]
        ]
      }, {
        content: "<p>This is a question</p><br><img src='https://hd.unsplash.com/photo-1467404899198-ccadbcd96b91'><br><p>This is a bit after the image</p>",
        mark: 12,
        methods: [
          [{
            mark: 3,
            content: "1a"
          }, {
            mark: 4,
            content: "1b"
          }, {
            mark: 5,
            content: "1c"
          }],
          [{
            mark: 3,
            content: "2a"
          }, {
            mark: 4,
            content: "2b"
          }, {
            mark: 5,
            content: "2c"
          }],
          [{
            mark: 3,
            content: "3a"
          }, {
            mark: 4,
            content: "3b"
          }, {
            mark: 5,
            content: "3c"
          }]
        ]
      });

      question.save();

      examBoard[0].module[0].topic[0].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[0].module[0].topic[0].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[0].module[0].topic[0].push(question[2]);
      examBoard[0].module[0].topic[1].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[0].module[0].topic[1].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[0].module[0].topic[1].push(question[2]);
      examBoard[0].module[0].topic[2].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[0].module[0].topic[2].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[0].module[0].topic[2].push(question[2]);
      examBoard[0].module[1].topic[0].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[0].module[1].topic[0].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[0].module[1].topic[0].push(question[2]);
      examBoard[0].module[1].topic[1].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[0].module[1].topic[1].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[0].module[1].topic[1].push(question[2]);
      examBoard[0].module[1].topic[2].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[0].module[1].topic[2].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[0].module[1].topic[2].push(question[2]);
      examBoard[0].module[2].topic[0].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[0].module[2].topic[0].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[0].module[2].topic[0].push(question[2]);
      examBoard[0].module[2].topic[1].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[0].module[2].topic[1].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[0].module[2].topic[1].push(question[2]);
      examBoard[0].module[2].topic[2].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[0].module[2].topic[2].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[0].module[2].topic[2].push(question[2]);
      examBoard[0].module[0].topic[0].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[0].module[0].topic[0].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[0].module[0].topic[0].push(question[2]);
      examBoard[0].module[0].topic[1].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[0].module[0].topic[1].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[0].module[0].topic[1].push(question[2]);
      examBoard[0].module[0].topic[2].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[0].module[0].topic[2].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[0].module[0].topic[2].push(question[2]);
      examBoard[0].module[1].topic[0].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[0].module[1].topic[0].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[0].module[1].topic[0].push(question[2]);
      examBoard[0].module[1].topic[1].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[0].module[1].topic[1].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[0].module[1].topic[1].push(question[2]);
      examBoard[0].module[1].topic[2].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[0].module[1].topic[2].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[0].module[1].topic[2].push(question[2]);
      examBoard[0].module[2].topic[0].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[0].module[2].topic[0].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[0].module[2].topic[0].push(question[2]);
      examBoard[0].module[2].topic[1].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[0].module[2].topic[1].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[0].module[2].topic[1].push(question[2]);
      examBoard[0].module[2].topic[2].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[0].module[2].topic[2].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[0].module[2].topic[2].push(question[2]);

      examBoard[1].module[0].topic[0].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[1].module[0].topic[0].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[1].module[0].topic[0].push(question[2]);
      examBoard[1].module[0].topic[1].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[1].module[0].topic[1].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[1].module[0].topic[1].push(question[2]);
      examBoard[1].module[0].topic[2].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[1].module[0].topic[2].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[1].module[0].topic[2].push(question[2]);
      examBoard[1].module[1].topic[0].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[1].module[1].topic[0].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[1].module[1].topic[0].push(question[2]);
      examBoard[1].module[1].topic[1].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[1].module[1].topic[1].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[1].module[1].topic[1].push(question[2]);
      examBoard[1].module[1].topic[2].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[1].module[1].topic[2].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[1].module[1].topic[2].push(question[2]);
      examBoard[1].module[2].topic[0].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[1].module[2].topic[0].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[1].module[2].topic[0].push(question[2]);
      examBoard[1].module[2].topic[1].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[1].module[2].topic[1].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[1].module[2].topic[1].push(question[2]);
      examBoard[1].module[2].topic[2].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[1].module[2].topic[2].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[1].module[2].topic[2].push(question[2]);

      examBoard[2].module[0].topic[0].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[2].module[0].topic[0].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[2].module[0].topic[0].push(question[2]);
      examBoard[2].module[0].topic[1].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[2].module[0].topic[1].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[2].module[0].topic[1].push(question[2]);
      examBoard[2].module[0].topic[2].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[2].module[0].topic[2].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[2].module[0].topic[2].push(question[2]);
      examBoard[2].module[1].topic[0].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[2].module[1].topic[0].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[2].module[1].topic[0].push(question[2]);
      examBoard[2].module[1].topic[1].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[2].module[1].topic[1].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[2].module[1].topic[1].push(question[2]);
      examBoard[2].module[1].topic[2].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[2].module[1].topic[2].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[2].module[1].topic[2].push(question[2]);
      examBoard[2].module[2].topic[0].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[2].module[2].topic[0].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[2].module[2].topic[0].push(question[2]);
      examBoard[2].module[2].topic[1].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[2].module[2].topic[1].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[2].module[2].topic[1].push(question[2]);
      examBoard[2].module[2].topic[2].push(question[0]);
      examBoard[2].module[2].topic[2].push(question[1]);
      examBoard[2].module[2].topic[2].push(question[2]);

      examBoard.save();
      console.log("Done seeding");
    }
  });
}

module.exports = seedDB;
```

The `examBoard` model

```js
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var topicSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  questions: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "question"
  }],
});

var moduleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  topics: [topicSchema]
});

var examBoardSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  modules: [moduleSchema]
});


module.exports = mongoose.model("examBoard", examBoardSchema);
```

Comment: can you provide the `./models/examBoard` file

Comment: Just added it, sorry for not thinking of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

`require` implements a singleton pattern, in mongoose when `require` a model, it's necessary to instance a new object, something like this:

```
var exam = new examBoard(request.body); // request.body can to contain the values of the schema structure
exam.save();
```

Comment: Not wholly sure what you mean do you mean I should do: 

var exam=new examBoard("./models/examBoard");

?

Comment: @JonathanWoollett-light It means that multiple `require` return single instance of module in node.js. Your `examBoard` file exports single value, which i guess is a function - constructor of model - and not a model instance itself. Thus it doesn't have `save()` method - it just not supposed to.

Answer (score 1):

The save method are only on the instance of an model, example

```
var examboard = new examBoard();
examboard.property = 'something';
examboard.save();
```

actually you already saving the objects when you say `examBoard.insertMany()`;

Comment: Do you mean to do:
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var examBoard = require("./models/examBoard");
var question = require("./models/question");
var user = require("./models/user");
var examboard = new examBoard();

function seedDB(){

Then replace all 'examBoard' within the function seedDB to 'examboard'

Comment: not exactly i am explaining that the save method is only for one object, if you want to insert many object need to be call from the collection itself as you are doing, see the mongoose doc http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html for a better explanation, in the section Constructing documents

Comment: how exactly would I fix this problem? I am very thankful for you telling me what the problem is, but (I think largely down to my ineptitude) I don't know how to solve it, and googling it has been of little help.